# PyCharm autocomplete/quick fix suggestions from (my own) unimported module?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on a python library with a bunch of packages and modules.  This is my module `mypack.aaa`

```
# mypack/aaa.py
class AClassNamedSue:
    pass
```

Now I'm working on another module, and I want it to end up like this:

```
# somewhere/bbb.py
from mypack.aaa import AClassNamedSue

def fun():
    return AClassNamedSue()
```

If I type in `AClassNamedSue`, I can hit alt-enter and then PyCharm will suggest the import, and hitting enter again, PyCharm will put the import statement there and I'm good.

Problem is, if I misspell `AClassNamedSue` or if I can't remember exactly what the class was named, then I have to go find it myself.  I would like to be able to type in `ACla` and then have PyCharm look through my project to suggest all classes/functions that I've written anywhere that start with `ACla`.

I understand that this could get heavy if I was asking for PyCharm to search through all of the packages installed with the interpreter, but I just want to be able to search through my own code for this sort of thing, which shouldn't be so bad.

I've looked through Settings->Editor->General->Code Completion and none of the settings there seem to do this. I'm not sure where else to look or whether this is possible.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try right clicking on the parent directory where all the modules files live, then "mark directory as" -> "source root"

Comment: That didn't help, pretty sure it was already my source root. PyCharm can already find my modules and packages, it's just that it won't suggest imports unless I've spelled the whole function/class name out completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling completion twice (`ACla` -> Ctrl + Space -> Ctrl + Space), see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html#invoke-basic-completion

Comment: Success! Thanks!